# Change column width of a table depending on other table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got 2 tables in which one table is only for header and another for showing data(I needed to scroll only table body so I used 2 Different tables) which will be loaded dynamically.
But now I need to change column width of first table according to the width of second table(because of no proper alignment between 2 table columns).
 Here is my code

```
 <div  runat="server" id="divmngprdcts" >
            <asp:Table runat="server" CssClass="prdctstbl">
             <asp:TableRow>
              <asp:TableCell ID="product0" CssClass="tblhead"">Image</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ID="product1"  CssClass="tblhead" >Product Id</asp:TableCell>
             <asp:TableCell ID="product2" CssClass="tblhead" >Name</asp:TableCell>
             <asp:TableCell ID="product3" CssClass="tblhead" >Category</asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell ID="product4" CssClass="tblhead" >Qty</asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell ID="product5" CssClass="tblhead" >Price</asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell ID="product6" CssClass="tblhead">Brand</asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
            </div>

           <div runat="server" id="divmngproducts" class="mngproducts">

              <asp:Table  runat="server" ID="tblprdcts" CssClass="prdctstbl">
            </asp:Table>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
.tblhead
{
    font-size:larger;
    padding:2px;
    text-align:center;
    color:Purple;
    background-color:#aeaeae;
    background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.9),rgba(220,220,220,1));
}

.prdctstbl
{
    width:98%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.mngproducts
{
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:95%;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: try `table-layout: fixed;`

Comment: Yeah. I even tried table-layout: fixed; but contents are overlapping.